# How to eval code as string to class name in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, eval

I'm trying to deserialize my URL parameters that contains a class name and then to test existing object against that class.

I thought I could retrieve the actual class with an `eval` like this

```
let type = eval(this.route.snapshot.queryParams['type']);
let id = +this.route.snapshot.queryParams['type'];

this.selectedResult = this.data.find(x => x.constructor === type && x.id === id);
```

But `eval` throws:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: MyClass is not defined

Indeed, when I put a breakpoint on the `eval` line, my business classes are not defined.

My guess is that the import does not really import the classes because it's only used to check types before compilation.

How can I do?

Comment: Using `eval` like this is a major security risk.  Denys's answer is good, or you could construct your own lookup table of class names to classes.  Indeed, TypeScript removes imports that are not needed at runtime.

Comment: downvoters, please comment

Comment: `eval` will likely get downvotes in any question

Comment: so why is there an `eval` tag ?

Comment: @YoukouleleY `eval` has an exaggerated reputation of being evil, which means many people will instantly dislike any question with it. To be fair the way *you* use it there *is* unsafe (which doesn't prevent your question from being valid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just check the constructor name:

```
x.constructor.name === this.route.snapshot.queryParams['type']
```

As a bonus this would be less a security risk for your users (your user's browser isn't evaling a random string which could have been given in for example in a link in a mail).

It still doesn't sound like a good idea to pass unfiltered code references in an URL: what if the actual class name changes ?

Comment: I serialize them like that `queryParams['type'] = event.constructor.name` so no impact if the name changes. I agree with you about the security concerns

Comment: will accept the answer as soon as I'm able to. Thanks for pointing out the risks of the eval, I just realized that it's an open door to creating malicious links to my app (looking safe when looking at the domain name)

Comment: I come back to provide some more informations. This solution does not work for a production build, because of minification. So, for every class, I was forced to define a static variable containing the name of the class, then use it for serialization, deserialization